# GAE bulkloader : entity missing from the auto-generated bulkloader.yaml

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am migrating a django application to GAE,and am going to use bulkloader to upload existing data.

The model is quite simple, basically there are two models:

```
class Tag(db.Model):
      name = db.StringProperty (required=True)

class Entry(db.Model):
      # some properties ...
      # ...
      tags = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

I ran `appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config` against my GAE app,and found two problems with the bulkloader.yaml generated:

1. Only kind `Entry` is generated,there is no kind `Tag` in the generated `bulkloader.yaml`.
2. In kind `Entry`, property `tags` is missing.

Also I noticed although I have code which inquiries model `Tag` like this:

```
Tag.gql('WHERE name = :1',t)
```

GAE doesn't generate index for `Tag` in `index.yaml`. I am wondering is this related to that `Tag` is missing from `bulkloader.yaml` ...

Any hints folks ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try running that GQL in the data store viewer in your control panel.

Comment: It turns out GAE updates its model statistics every 24hours. I waited for 2 days and run the script again all entities are created in the bulkload.xml